# How to custom title of bulk toolbar in <List /> react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I would like to custom `title` of `Toolbar` in `List` component of `ReactAdmin`

How to add more `text` as `2 items selected`: Like `2 items selected (SUM: 20000)`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override RA default translations like that

```
import _merge from 'lodash.merge';
import polyglotI18nProvider from 'ra-i18n-polyglot';
import frenchMessages from 'ra-language-french';
import React from 'react';

const i18nProvider = polyglotI18nProvider(() =>
  _merge(frenchMessages, {
    ra: {
      action: {
        bulk_actions:
          '%{smart_count} sélectionné |||| %{smart_count} sélectionnés',
      },
    },
  })
);

function App(): ReactElement {

  return (
    <Admin i18nProvider={i18nProvider}>
      ...your resources here
    </Admin>
  );
}

export default App;
```